# Where is the getFormAction method

Tags: magento-1.8, template, forms, contact-us, action

I have a custom template and in the beginning there is this line

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

My installation is `something_me/...` and the `getFormAction()` returns `something/...`, so I wanted to check the function (because probably the URL is hardcoded and I want to change that). But the module (a custom one) does not have a controller and the block of that template does not have a `getFormatAction()` function.

By debugging I tried going to the function but it only leads me to the `__call()` function and then back to the template.

So how can I see where is that action implemented and change the behaviour of acquiring the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getformaction()
```

Please follow the below directory structure : And find the required Answer,
it may help you to customize your block
Defined at:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php -> line 75
/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Customer/Edit.php -> line 50
/app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/Block/Placeform.php -> line 58
```

Referenced 5 times:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml -> line 31
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/list.phtml -> line 39
/app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/contacts/form.phtml -> line 31
/app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/tag/customer/edit.phtml -> line 31
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/moneybookers/placeform.phtml -> line 29
```